# Custom menu-items permissions are erased when features are refreshed

Tags: routes, features

I am using D7.37 with [features 7.x-2.5](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) and [Features Tools 7.x-2.x-dev](https://www.drupal.org/project/ftools) (2014-Nov-27). I have 2 environments (dev, prod), and I use git and features to sync.

After I refresh features and download to the file system (updated), the menu-item permissions tend to be erased.

This is killing me, since menus are the face of the system. Any ideas?